# unsupported PDF when printing from Thunderbird

Tags: printing, google-chrome, pdf, thunderbird

I am using PrintNG on Thunderbird current production (not Thunderbird Supernova) under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS current.  From some emails, I get a PDF not supported type of diagnostic as one line hardcopy output when I print to the CUPS printer, whereas other PDF emails print correctly. The Adobe answer is [Adobe Acrobat does not exist on Linux](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/unsupported-pdf-data-for-direct-print-1000/td-p/10673167). However, when I save the file as a PDF (not directly print) and then use Atril (not an Adobe product) to print to the same CUPS printer, the output is correct.  How does one force any PDF file to be hardcopy printed from Firefox or Thunderbird to be piped through Atril?  Note that Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge (both Ubuntu applications) do not have this issue.  I have read the various URLs that Ask Ubuntu provided, but none are relevant -- I want an "automatic" solution that will remain in whatever configuration file or script after upgrades to "force" printing of a PDF item from Thunderbird to be done through Atril without requiring me to first save the PDF as a file, then open and print it from Atril.